# Cmt migration tool validation error

Tags: openvz, runc

I am using cmt (https://github.com/marcosnils/cmt) for container migration and I have problem in the validation.

```
# cmt validate --src `pwd` --dst walid@192.168.1.12

2016/01/11 17:31:53 Error criu does not exist in dst
```

I am sure both have the patched version of criu (https://github.com/marcosnils/criu) on both servers.

And I even tried it the other way around with the same result.

Answer (score 1):

The error seems to be because all the tools needs a sudo permission.

so to remove this need.

Add this to end of /etc/sudoers

```
'walid ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL'
```

After this the validation successes

Comment: this is done by the help of @Marcos Nils https://github.com/marcosnils/cmt/issues/12